# Clean url mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a url

```
www.mysite.com/folder/details.php?d=sample.com
```

and I want it to change like this one

```
www.mysite.com/folder/sample.com
```

This is my .htaccess file, but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ details.php?d=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ details.php?d=$1
```

I also tried this one, but its not working also:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule folder/([0-9]+) details.php?d=$1
```

This is my url link php code:

```
<a href="details.php?d=<?php echo $var['var']; ?>"><?php echo $var['var']; ?></a>
```

I tried some of the answers I found in this site but still I cannot figured out what I am doing wrong. Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but "sample.com" may need periods to be allowed:  ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)$

Comment: It says, Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments @Jon Lin and @quasivivo , I found a solution to my problem, this is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ /portfolio/details.php?d=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and I also change my url link code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $var['var']; ?>"><?php echo $var['var']; ?></a>
```

Hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need some conditions to prevent looping:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ details.php?d=$1 [L]
```

You can also combine the two rules into one by using the `/?` at the end to make the slash optional.

---

For the rules to be placed in the document root, you need to add the folder names to the pattern and the target:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ /folder/details.php?d=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried the code above sir, but its not working, I am getting Internal Server Error

Comment: And this is in the htaccess file in the `/folder/` directory?

Comment: No, my .htaccess is outside the /folder/. But I add an .htaccess file inside the /folder/ with your suggested code above, but the code is still not working.

Comment: @zen you sure mod_rewrite is loaded? do you have other rules anywhere else? The rules work fine for me

Comment: May I ask sir how to know if mod_rewrite is loaded? Still newbie here sir, hehe

Comment: @zen https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=how+to+tell+if+mod_rewrite+is+loaded&oq=how+to+tell+if+mod_rewrite+is+loaded

Comment: @zen Actually, I had the `.` and `-` reversed

Comment: The mod_rewrite is enable. I'm still confuse, where did I go wrong,

Comment: @zen the regular expression was malformed, I edited it in the answer

Comment: I edit the code as what you said: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)/?$ details.php?d=$1 [L], but still I receive 500 Internal Server Error :(

Comment: @zen you **sure** you have a `details.php` file in the `/folder/`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Should I put the htaccess inside the /folder/directory?

Comment: yes, put it in your `/folder/` directory, unless you have a reason not to (like if you wanted all your rules in one place)

Comment: Is it posible to put it in one .htaccess file all the rewrite rules?